# Chatgpt multiple REST API request from Google Cloud function error

Tags: google-cloud-functions, openai-api

I have a problem regarding ChatGPT API, in my Google cloud functions there are 3 functions that are triggered simultaneously the 3 functions calls ChatGPT. The problem is that usually 2 out of 3 API requests gets called and the third returns undefined. How this can be solved from ChatGPT side or Google cloud functions?

Comment: Can you provide any more details, more details on the functions would be great?  What do the functions do and what are they specifically calling?